# Eclipse CDT on OS X complaining about gcc built-in function: "Function '__builtin_bzero' could not be resolved"

Tags: c++, eclipse, sockets, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I am working on some c++ network code in Eclipse CDT as a makefile project but eclipse is complaining about `FD_ZERO`. Compiling is working fine.

Minimal example:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void test()
{
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
}
```

This shows up in as "Eclipse is `Function '__builtin_bzero' could not be resolved`" error.

This `FD_ZERO` is a macro defined in `sys/select.h'

```
sys/select.h:#define    FD_ZERO(p)  __DARWIN_FD_ZERO(p)
```

and in `sys/_structs.h` we can find `__DARWIN_FD_ZERO` to be defined as a call to a gcc built-in function.

```
#define __DARWIN_FD_ZERO(p)     __builtin_bzero(p, sizeof(*(p)))
```

I have selected mac os x tool chain in CDT and not altered any other options.
Any ideas to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this hasn't been answered yet, so for completeness, this is my solution:

Use `memset(&fds, 0, sizeof fds);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that __builtin_bzero is just that, it's builtin at the compiler level.  CDT doesn't know that because it has its own parser.